# Show that if the ratios of coefficients is unbounded, then the power series converges only at 0

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have a question about Exercise 6.5.8(d) from Understanding Analysis by Stephen Abbott.

Problem:
Let $\sum a_nx^n$ be a power series with $a_n\neq0$. Show that if $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$ is unbounded, then the original series $\sum a_nx^n$ converges only when $x = 0$.

I have come up with a possible counterexample.
Let $(a_n)=(1,\frac{1}{2},1,\frac{1}{3},1,\frac{1}{4},\dots)$. Then $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$ is unbounded.

For $x=\frac{1}{2}$,

$$
\sum a_n x^n =\sum a_n \frac{1}{2^n}
$$
Since each $0<a_n\leq1$, the partial sums of the series is bounded by the infinite geometric series $\sum \frac{1}{2^n}$. As each term is positive, we can use the monotone convergence theorem to show the series converges at $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

However, this contradicts the claim in the question that the series only converges when $x=0$.

So, my question is: why does this counterexample not work? Thanks

Comment: Your counterexample works. Abbott writes in his instructor's manual for the first edition: "The statement in this exercise is false. A condition such as $|a_{n+1} / a_n| \geq 1$ for _all_ values of $n$ after some point in the sequence would be sufficient to prove the series diverges."

Comment: ah ok that answers my question. thanks!